# How to make npm install a scoped package without scope name?

Tags: azure, npm, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to install some packages from Azure Artifacts Feed which was set up by my organization. I still need other external packages in https://registry.npmjs.org/. Although they have configured NPM as upstream source for feed, my 'Reader' permission doesn't allow me to add new packages. So I can only use NPM scopes to install private packages from a scope registry and public package from official registry. But I cannot install private packages simply with scope name.

I've config my user's `.npmrc`, get authentication using "`vsts-npm-auth`". It looks like this now:

```
    # $HOME\.npmrc
    proxy=http://my-enterprise-proxy.com
    noproxy[]=blah-blah-blah
    strict-ssl=false
    registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
    
    @feed-scope:registry:=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[ORGANIZATION_NAME]/_packaging/[FEED_NAME]/npm/registry/
    always-auth=true
    //pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/:username=[ENTER_ANY_VALUE_BUT_NOT_AN_EMPTY_STRING]
    //pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
    //pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
```

Now I try to execute:

```
npm install @feed-scope/package-needed
```

And I get:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/@my-scope%2fpackage-needed - The package '@my-scope/package-needed' was not found in feed '[FEED_NAME]'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@my-scope/package-needed@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I've explored my org's feed, there is only a package named "package-needed". I doubt that the scope name I add to command just what the problem is. But I don't know how can I remove it.

PS: Please ignore those placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not going to work. The scope is part of an npm package's name. You should work with the owners of your feed to get you the *Collaborator*  role, which is the same as the Reader role plus the ability to use packages from upstreams which have not yet been saved to your feed. This is distinct from the *Contributor* role which also adds the ability to publish packages directly to the feed.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to get in touch with them.